# Parameter passing cost for Binary search algorithm

Tags: algorithms

The implication of three parameter passing techniques are given

1. An arrays is passed by pointer. Time = $\theta$(1).
2. An array is passed by copying. Time = $\theta$(N). Where N is the size of the array
3. An array is passed by copying only the sub-range that might be accessed by the called procedure. Time = $\theta$(q-p+1) if the sub-array A[p..q] is passed.

Now it is asked to find the recurrences for the worst-case running time of Binary search algorithm when the arrays are passed using above three methods.

the normal recurrence for B.S algo is

$T(n)= T(n/2) + \theta(C)$.

so according to the question there will be added cost of parameter passing, the recurrence becomes

for 1. $T(n)= T(n/2) + \theta(C) + \theta(C^{'})$. where $\theta(C^{'})$ is the parameter passing cost.

for 2 it will be $T(n)= T(n/2) + \theta(C) + \theta(N)$
 i am getting answers as

for 1 $\theta(log n)$ and for 2 $\theta(n log n)$.

is my method correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your method is correct.

As intuitive proof you can think that (1) is obviously the normal binary search, therefore you have to do $θ(\log n)$ steps. For (2) you have to copy the whole array at each step, and since you have as many steps as in (1), you have $θ(n) \cdot θ(\log n)$ complexity. The last case is very similar to the second one.